# How to Add KmlLayer to M4B Google Map For Business?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, kml, kmz

I need to add KmlLayer to Google map for business as the following steps.

first of all, I am using "Google maps utils" with the following Gradle

```
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
```

and as this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/kml)

and below is the applied code :

```
try {
    KmlLayer kmlLayer = new KmlLayer(googleMap, R.raw.traiff160809, RTA.getContext());
    kmlLayer.addLayerToMap();
} catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

but I cannot pass Google map for business instance at the constructor

Advice please,
Thanks !